# How to translate a string in custom form

Tags: transcribe, multi-language, translation

I am very new to Expression Engine. I have a template file and added a new text filed in it. Now I want to translate the string into multiple languages.

Where I need to include my translated string.

Please do help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExpressionEngine does not have multi-lingual features in its base configuration, but you can add these via an add-on: there are at least two very good options available.

- [Publisher](https://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher)
- [Transcribe](https://eeharbor.com/transcribe)

Both are powerful multi-lingual solutions that make it possible to build and manage true multi-lingual sites.  Both are from well respected commercial providers, are widely used and are well supported.

If you don't want to translate the whole site and just want to translate a few words you might be better off sorting out a solution yourself.  How that works very much depends on what you are trying to do: if you explain more about what your aim is maybe someone can offer a clearer answer on the self-build route.

As a general house-keeping rule, questions about ExpressionEngine are usually more usefully answered if you include basic information about your set-up in your question - in particular letting people know what version of EE you are working with, and if your question extends into areas such as add-ons, or php etc including information about what versions of those you are using also.

HTH

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you suggest me any plugin to automatic translation?

Comment: If you mean something that hooks into an automatic translation service it is possible to do this, but I am not aware of any add-ons that are available for EE to support this.  You can find out more about this (for example, imagine Google offers similar) from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/web/